# HTML meta refresh won't redirect to targeted page

Tags: html, redirect, refresh

I'm trying to make my HTML page to redirect automatically to my school's website, but it won't do it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    div.a {
      text-align: center;
      font-family: verdana;
      height: 200px;
      width: 400px;
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-top: -100px;
      margin-left: -200px;
    }
    
    div.b {
      text-align: center;
      font-family: verdana;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 30px;
      width: 100%
    }
  </style>

  <meta charset="utf-8" , charset="ISO-8859-1" />
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" , content="3" ; url="https://www.utad.pt/" />

  <title>Redirecionando para Utad.pt</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="Redirecionando" , class="a">
    <strong>Aguarde, redirecionando-o para Utad...</strong>
    <br>
    <br>
    <img src="http://moodle.utad.pt/theme/evolved/layout/includes/hmmm1/img/logo-big.png" ; align="center" ; width="135px" ; height="120px" />
  </div>

  <div id="manual" class="b">
    Caso a página não carregue: <a href="https://utad.pt/">Utad.pt</a>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The page refreshes every 3 seconds, but it refuses to redirect. I want to say that I didn't do anything wrong, but if it's not doing it, it means I screwed up somewhere.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="refresh", content="3; url=https://www.utad.pt/" />
Notice that url is inside content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `content` attribute value in your `meta` `http-equiv` tag to include both the refresh interval and the url. Like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=https://www.utad.pt/" />
```

Comment: I feel dumb now, I knew there was something wrong with the url, after Sublime wouldn't give me a prompt when typing it. Thank you!